# ROS Installation on Red Hat7

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to install ROS (Indigo) on Red Hat7 according to the this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source).

When I try to install all the required dependencies using the following commands:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:

rqt_robot_steering: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS [rhel]
catkin: No definition of [python-nose] for OS [rhel]
class_loader: No definition of [libpoco-dev] for OS [rhel]
urdf: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS [rhel]
...
```

Is there any way to install all the required dependencies on Red Hat? Thank you!

---

Edit:

Hello,  thank you for this quick reply. I tried the following command instead

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo --os=fedora:2
```

Then, I received:

```
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

But, I got the following error messages when I go through the next step, step 2.1.3 to build the catkin workspace.

```
CMake Error at /u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindPoco.cmake:186 (MESSAGE): Poco was not found.  Set the Poco_INCLUDE_DIR cmake cache entry to the top-level directory containing the poco include directories.  E.g /usr/local/include/ or c:\poco\include\poco-1.3.2

Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package) -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! <== Failed to process package 'class_loader':
```

I think that it still has dependency problems.. Thank you.

---

Updated!

Yes, there was no error when I type the command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo --os=fedora:21
```

The failed package is 'class_loader':

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
<== Failed to process package 'class_loader':
  Command '['/u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/src/class_loader', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/class_loader', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Thank you very much for your help!

---

Edit:

Now, I'm facing the following error message:

```
CMake Warning at /u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:66 (message):
  skipping gtest 'test_urdf' in project 'pr2_description'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:34 (catkin_add_executable_with_gtest)
  CMakeLists.txt:94 (catkin_add_gtest)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:95 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "test_urdf" which is not built by
  this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 cd /u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pr2_description && /u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/src/pr2_common/pr2_description -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pr2_description -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/u/leejang/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'
```

I tried to search solution here, but I couldn't find..

---

Edit:

Thank you gvdhoorn for your kindly reply.  Now, I've completed install with ROS-common packages (NO GUI tools). I think that it's enough for my current project. So, I close this question.

Thank you again I really appreciate your helps!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216929/ros-installation-on-red-hat7/) by [Jangwon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22582/jangwon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-09-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-02**:
Can you check that the Poco library and headers are actually installed? What is the output of `find /usr -name Poco.h`?

**Comment by [Jangwon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22582/jangwon/) on 2015-09-02**:
Thank you! It wasn't there, so I installed it and the problem was solved. Now, I'm facing other problem about Eigen3, but it seems that it also wasn't my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see whether [Compiling on centos7](http://answers.ros.org/question/216564/compiling-on-centos7/) helps.

---

Edit:

> But, I got the following error messages when I go through the next step, step 2.1.3 to build the catkin workspace.
> [..]

Seems like some package depends on the Poco library, but either didn't declare it, or Poco is a transitive dependency of something on Fedora, but not on RHEL7. Can you please update your question with a bit more context? What package failed to configure?

As to a solution / work-around: you could try to see whether you can install `poco-devel` manually (at least, that's what I assume it is called on RHEL). A quick search did not turn up any RHEL7 package for that though. Are you sure there were no errors when you ran the `rosdep install .. --os=fedora:2` command?

Also: remember: doing an install this way is really nothing more than a work-around. The proper way would be to [contribute rosdep rules](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) for RedHat.

---

Edit2:

> ```
>   skipping gtest 'test_urdf' in project 'pr2_description'
> ```

and:

> ```
> Cannot specify link libraries for target "test_urdf" which is not built by this project.
> ```

It would seem you don't have `gtest` installed, which causes [this line](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_common/blob/21e0c1a5a5c4ec3a7a9527fa17dcafb8478edcc3/pr2_description/CMakeLists.txt#L94) to probably fail. The next line tries to then link the `test_urdf` target with some other library, but since the `test_urdf` target doesn't exist, it fails the entire build.

Please make sure you have `gtest` installed. If you can't install it, you might be able to skip all testing by appending `-DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=False` to your `catkin_make` invocation. The `pr2_description` package will still fail though, as it hasn't been properly setup (see [pr2_common/issues/241](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_common/issues/241) and [pr2_common/pull/238](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_common/pull/238)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3